# Can not authenticate to Google Cloud

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-authentication

I am trying to use Google Cloud Translation API, but I can not authenticate to Google Cloud.

```
TranslationServiceClient client = TranslationServiceClient.create()
```

This line fires the error below:

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

I have created the project on Google Cloud, downloaded the json file when I created the Service Account as required by the API and I exported the parameters using command line but still not working:

> export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/admin/Desktop/franzosischlernen-d8db6-9457de40bc93.json"

Comment: Are you sure that your `GOOGLE _APPLICATION-CREDENTIALS` env var is loaded in your runtime context? Can your perform a check by logging the System.getenv()(...) value?

Comment: I checked `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, it is not loaded

Comment: Did you find the solution? Only your workstation misconfiguration? Do you need more help on this question?

Comment: Not yet, I don't know where I should load it if not command line

Comment: how do you run your java app? Do you use an IDE?

Comment: I am using Android Studio